# HyperLink to Word Doc in Safari

Tags: html, macos

A very simple question however I cant seem to resolve the issue.

I have a HTML file with a link to a word doc.

In IE/PC it works fine in Safari on the mac I get a blank TAB that opens up.

```
The HTML Code:
<a href=-"./MyDoc.docx">Open Word File</a>
```

Any Ideas ?

The same structure to other file types works such as .mp4 and pdf, but not DOCX or PPT

Comment: I think whats happening is that it may be opening up in Finder rather than openining the App associated with it.
If so, how can this be changed to launch the external App  ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, but I would suggest this:

```
<a href=-"./MyDoc.docx" target="_self">Open Word File</a>
```